# Как сделать копию функции, что бы у копии был отличный от оригинала ID (deepcopy не работает)

Tags: python

Есть простая функция

```
def foo(n): return n
```

необходимо сделать копию данной функции, чтобы `id` были разные. Если делать при помощи `deepcopy`, то копия ссылается на оригинал.

Comment: `id` функции чтобы был другой или чего `id`? Ну просто `def bar(*args, **kwargs): foo(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: нужна полноценная копия. Грубо говоря, чтобы оригинал не вызывался при вызове копии

Comment: Можно вопрос: _зачем_?

Comment: @Максим А как кто-то будет узнавать, что вызвался оригинал? Если код для этой проверки есть внутри функции, то он же и в новую функцию скопируется. Не совсем всё понятно с этой задачей.

Comment: хотел предложить  `b=pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a))` но питон кеширует байткод и функция развернулась в тот же id

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос, нашел такое решение.

```
>>> def foo(n): return n

>>> id(foo)
123294917623008
>>> import copy, types
>>> a=types.FunctionType(copy.copy(foo.__code__), globals())
>>> id(a)
123294919822208
>>> a(123)
123
```

`globals()` - контекст функции, можно поставить туда: `locals()` , пустой  словарь `{}` или сформировать свой контекст вручную, старый `foo.__globals__` или его копию